# How to build subplots of pandas data frames within a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create a function that creates sub-data frames of like variables (via regex). Next, each of these sub-data frames is plotted as a subplot on an axes within a figure. The function outputs the figure and an outline of all subplots, but no data is plotted.

I looked at several post on the site including "pandas subplots in a loop" and "subplots with a for loop". The questions I searched with similar topics have very different problems.

```
def plot_macro_trend_cycle(df):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8)) 
        for col,num in zip(df.columns,range(1,len(df.columns)+1)):

            df0 =pd.DataFrame(df.filter(regex = '{}'.format(col)), index = df.index)
            ax = fig.add_subplot(round((len(df.columns)/2)),2,num)
            ax.set_ylabel('{}'.format(col))  
            ax.set_xlabel('{}'.format(col))
            ax.set_title('{}'.format(col), pad=20)
        df0.plot(y = [df0.columns[0],df0.columns[1]], linewidth=0.5, ax=ax,legend=None)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

Here is an image of the error I receive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg1VY.png)

Comment: You are defining a new df0 variable on each iteration of your `for` loop and only plotting the last df0 dataframe after the loop. Indent your df0.plot() line inside the loop.

Comment: thank you so much. I'll try to select this as the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a new `df0` variable on each iteration of your `for` loop and only plotting the last `df0` dataframe after the loop. Indent your `df0.plot()` line inside the loop.